# Split file according to patterns in two consecutive lines

Tags: bash, sed, split, awk, lines

I have files with the following format:

```
ATOM   3736  CB  THR A 486      -6.552 153.891  -7.922  1.00115.15           C  
ATOM   3737  OG1 THR A 486      -6.756 154.842  -6.866  1.00114.94           O  
ATOM   3738  CG2 THR A 486      -7.867 153.727  -8.636  1.00115.11           C  
ATOM   3739  OXT THR A 486      -4.978 151.257  -9.140  1.00115.13           O  
HETATM10351  C1  NAG A 203      33.671  87.279  39.456  0.50 90.22           C  
HETATM10483  C1  NAG A 702      28.025 104.269 -27.569  0.50 92.75           C    
ATOM   3736  CB  THR B 486      -6.552  86.240   7.922  1.00115.15           C  
ATOM   3737  OG1 THR B 486      -6.756  85.289   6.866  1.00114.94           O  
ATOM   3738  CG2 THR B 486      -7.867  86.404   8.636  1.00115.11           C  
ATOM   3739  OXT THR B 486      -4.978  88.874   9.140  1.00115.13           O  
HETATM10351  C1  NAG B 203      33.671 152.852 -39.456  0.50 90.22           C  
HETATM10639  C2  FUC B 402     -48.168 162.221 -22.404  0.50103.03           C
```

I would like to split the file after each line starting with HETATM* but only if the next line starts with ATOM. I would like the new files to be called $basename_$column, where $basename is the base name of the input file and $column is the character at position 22-23 (either A or B, in the example). I am not able to figure out how to check both consecutive lines to determine the splitting point.

Comment: In awk, you could use `next` and `print ... > filename` to accomplish the task. Use a global variable to look at the _previous_ line.

Comment: Would a Python script work for you?

Comment: Sure. Initially, I wanted to avoid any external scripts. But this is taking longer than expected due to the numerous exceptions encountered when parsing data. This is my first serious attempt of coding ever and I have already written 500 lines in a few days... What I need now is getting the job done ASAP no matter how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple Python solution with no error checking. Should work in Python 2 or 3; change the first line to match your environment. Don't take this as an example of good coding style.

Edited for unique file names.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.4

import os.path
import sys

fname = sys.argv[1]
bname = os.path.basename(fname)

fin = open(fname)

fout = None
ct = 0

for line in fin:
    if line[:6] == 'HETATM':
        flag = True
    if (not fout) or (flag and line[:4] == 'ATOM'):
        if fout:
            fout.close()
        ct += 1
        fout = open(bname + '_' + line[21:22] + str(ct), 'w')
        flag = False
    fout.write(line)

fout.close()
```

Comment: It works! Thanks you. The only problem is that when I have duplicated chain names, it overwrites the previous file with the new one. This means that if I have two chains named A it will write file_A once and then will overwrite it with the next occurrence. I need to figure out a way to prevent this from happening. Maybe the bes way is adding a counter so that I will write file_A1, file_B2, fileC3, file_A4 and so on...

Comment: @mirix: Ok, new version should do that. I didn't test it.

Answer (score 3):

Here's an `awk` version

```
awk 'NR==1{n=$5}/HETATM/{f=1}f && /^ATOM/{n=$5;f=0}{print > "file"n".txt"}' file
```

Use `FILENAME` instead of `file` to create the same file name.

Comment: I'll have to spend more time with awk, it's sure a lot shorter than my solution.

Comment: @Tom : This far, your python script has demonstrated to be 100% reliable, whereas this awk script makes some mistakes in more complex situations than the one provided as example.

Comment: @mirix, its all in the programming dude. Given any situation, my awk solution can be fine tuned to match that of Python's .... since its just file/text parsing..

Comment: @ghostdog74; yes, in fact the reason why your awk one-liner is not working is the following (as explained in other thread): Sometimes, with large values in the second column, there is no space left between the first and second columns, so from the awn point of view, that is just one column and therefore the 5th column becomes the 4th. In the PDB format, each field occupies a fixed position and therefore it is better to provide the specific position rather than using delimiters. Is it possible to specify a range in awk? I mean something like $22-$25 (with -F "")?